# What does this quotation symbolize in A Christmas Carol; “I cannot rest I cannot stay I cannot linger anywhere”?

Tags: a-christmas-carol, the-muppet-christmas-carol

What is the meaning of this quote and the device used?

> “I cannot rest I cannot stay I cannot linger anywhere”.

Answer (score 7):

From a literary perspective, there are a few different devices at play here;

- Marley's Ghost is an example of *[**prosopopoeia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopopoeia)*, the presentation of a dead thing that can speak to a living person.
- Marley is giving us (the audience) and Scrooge (the protagonist) [***exposition***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposition_(narrative)) regarding his present state and the upcoming events of the "carol".
- He is obeying the [***rule of three***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)#Literature), talking in groups of three to presage the fact that there will be three ghosts to teach him three lessons.
- The sentence is an example of [***grammatical parallelism***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)), with the third clause being subtly different from the previous two in order to 'balance' the sentence.
- Dickens is using [***meter***](http://homepage.smc.edu/meeks_christopher/SOUND%20DEVICES%20USED%20IN%20POETRY.htm) to make Marley's speech patterns less human and more ghostly.
- Marley is using [***repetition***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device)) to emphasis quite how deep his troubles are, stressing that there are no loopholes for him (a man of laws) to exploit.
- It goes without saying that "Rest", "Stay" and "Linger" are all [***synonyms***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym) of each other and an example of [***elegant variation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation), with Marley basically saying the same thing three times over. This stresses his predicament as well as drawing the audience's attention to his intelligence.

---

As to its meaning, there's the absolutely literal (he's trapped) as well as the inherent threat that Scrooge is similarly ensnared, he just doesn't know it yet.

Comment: Not sure what _A Christmas Carol_ has to do with SFF, but hey, it's a very nice answer for a question that shoulda been posted over at [english.se]! Have a vote (like you need another...)

Comment: @FreeMan - Did you perhaps miss the part with the ghosts?

Comment: Oh. I guess didn't realize ghosts automatically make it "fantasy". OK, @TIL...

Comment: @FreeMan - I'd argue that any supernatural presence makes a property *broadly* on-topic. Having them be integral to the plot makes a property **firmly** on-topic